# Recover partition after moving to LVM2

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery

I had two ext4 partitions. The first containing an old linux Mint OS and the 2nd containing backups. I started a fresh installation of Linux Mint from a live CD. At partition options I've choosen LVM and thought it's about the first partition. I canceled but the installation already created the following.
[GParted partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F03uY.png)

Is there a way to recover the old partitions? I tried testdisk but had no success. Also I found posts helping to restore old LVM volumes, but no help for restoring data after moving to LVM.

Answer (score 0):

After a newly started deep search with `testdisk` in the LVM Container a few hundred filesystems are found. Most of them empty due to damaged filesystem. Happily one found filesystem contained my precious files. For those who have this problem it makes sense to go deeper into `testdisk` and have some patience. And make a backup of your device using `dd`.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the partitions exactly as they were, including the following details:

1. Partition table type (MBR, GPT)
2. First and last sectors

While recreating the partitions, some partition editors will report a found filesystem signature and ask if you want to overwrite it (or similar language, I don't remember exactly). You want to preserve it, not overwrite it.

If you manage to do all of that, and nothing was written to those partitions in the interim, you should have your volumes back and intact. If anything was written to the device after those partitions were deleted, you may still be able to recover data from them, but the first step would be to recreate them and then run fsck on them to check integrity.